# Running a preprocessor w/ Pixate Freestyle iOS

Tags: ios, css, sass, pixate

I stumbled across [Pixate](http://www.pixate.com/) today and I'm really excited about it.
As awesome as it is, CSS could be improved, particularly with a preprocessor. I'm not very familiar with the anatomy of preprocessors so my question to SO is if it's possible to implement a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) with Pixate so that writing sass will compile all the way into Objective-C on an iOS application. How cool would that be?!

Comment: Did you mistake SO for Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already possible to use Sass, Less, Stylus, etc. :)

http://www.pixate.com/blog/2013-01-19-sass/

Answer (score 1):

To add to Clifton's answer, there are updated instructions for Freestyle with Sass here: https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/tree/master/themes#compiling-sass

Comment: Wow that must have either just been added or I missed it the first time. Brilliant!